# Internal DNS issue

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, cloudflare

Our internal network has been setup with the same domain as our external website.

We currently point a www record at the server IP (acquia) - this works but  means we don’t get cloudflare’s management and SSL etc

I’m wondering if there’s any way to actually get our internal DNS to resolve to cloudflare?

Thanks,
Stuart

Comment: Why do you point the record at the server? Why aren’t you pointing the record at cloudflare?

Comment: If you purchase a domain.Then what is the point of creating a same in your network.You can use the same....?

Comment: If you create same domain in internal DNS the resolution will never go outside unless you change DNS server on client

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add NS records internally for the www subdomain and point it to your public dns nameservers, you could also add a 'forward zone' if you provided more information like what dns server you're using you'd get a more precise answer.

Basically;

**Nameserver**

```
dig +short NS example.com
```

then add 
`www.example.com IN NS <result from above>` to your internal DNS

Or

**zone forward**

```
zone "www.example.com" {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders { 1.1.1.1; 8.8.8.8; };
};
```

Next time, use a subdomain like ad.contoso.com or lan.contoso.com